# Current row in VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, row

How can I **determine the current row where a selection is active of the table in a Word VBA macro**?

I've tried all variants with no success:

```
MsgBox Selection.Range
MsgBox Selection.Rows.Item.Index
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

```
MsgBox Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)
MsgBox Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex
```

Comment: And also `Selection.Information(wdStartOfRangeRowNumber)`